# What is the purpose of apply maven plugin in build.gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, build, build.gradle

I keep seeing `apply plugin: 'maven'` in build.gradle files for Java projects. What is the purpose of adding a Maven plugin? I can't seem to find the plugin when querying for it on [plugins.gradle.org](https://plugins.gradle.org/).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Why don't you just google it?
http://sorcersoft.org/project/site/gradle/userguide/maven_plugin.html

"The Maven plugin adds support for deploying artifacts to Maven repositories."

Comment: is this something old btw? cause there is `maven-publish` that I have always been using, first time I hear about `maven`; in case you are aware of

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't find that page when I searched for it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).